# Adding Zxing Lib for J2ME Project in NetBeans

Tags: java-me, zxing

I have have download Zxing-1.7 ( Which is deprecated , but want to develope with it for J2ME Project )

Can any one tell me, how to add this Zxing-1.7 lib to J2ME project. Am using NetBeans IDE.

Help me. Am very new to J2ME and all.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see when looking at http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ there is no JavaME version of the lib available. You cannot expect a JavaSE version to work in a JavaME project.
So you'll have to edit the source and create a JavaME port of the lib first.

Since you're going to do that anyway, you might want to just include the sources directly into your own project. But if you insist on compiling it as a library and include that library in your project then go to

Project Properties -> Libraries and Resources

and click "Add Jar/Zip".